# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: php, jquery, json

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
в файле
доменное-имя.com.ua/wp-content/themes/draco/getPrice.php?yrs=1&pcs=1&pid=82

Код файла getPrice.php

```html
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');

global $wpdb;

//$price = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT price FROM prices where years = ".$_GET['yrs']." and pcs = ".$_GET['pcs']." and product_id = ".$_GET['pid']." limit 1 "));
$price = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT price FROM prices, buy_link where years = ".$_GET['yrs']." and pcs = ".$_GET['pcs']." and product_id = ".$_GET['pid']." limit 1 "));

header('Content-Type: application/json');
http_response_code(200);

echo json_encode($price);
 
?>
```

При смене цены в select выбивает ошибку.

> jquery.min.js:4 GET
>   http://bitdefender.com.ua/wp-content/themes/draco/getPrice.php?yrs=1&pcs=3&pid=82
>   404 (Not Found)jquery.min.js:4 sendjquery.min.js:4
>   n.extend.ajax(index):45 get_price(index):229 onchange

Всё это на странице - http://bitdefender.com.ua/product/bitdefender-antivirus-plus-2015/

Скриншот: [image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Подскажите в чём может быть проблема. Заранее огромное Аригато!

Comment: Нет такого файла по такому адресу

Comment: Когда нету - 404 ошибка. А тут всё ок - http://bitdefender.com.ua/wp-content/themes/draco/getPrice.php?yrs=null&pcs=null&pid=23

Comment: Во-первых, тут и так 404 ошибка. Во-вторых, я прошел по вашей ссылке и получил ту же 404.

Comment: @СтаниславКучер, не всё ок, т.к. ответ = 404, см. http://pastebin.com/f97Tv2ek

Comment: @СтаниславКучер, и кстати, WTF? SELECT price FROM prices, buy_link where years = ".$_GET['yrs'].". я не знаю на сколько волшебна функция $wpdb->prepare, но один фиг вы в запрос вставляете данные из реквеста, не лучше ли заюзать параметры?

Comment: Вижу Действительно при вызове файла с параметрами даёт ошибку. А если просто вбить файл, то всё ок. Сейчас буду искать что это.

Comment: Вызывается с параметрами здесь(из ajax).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  function get_price(pid, currency, URL)
  {
   var yrs = $('#years').val(); 
   var usrs =$('#usrs').val();  
   
   $.ajax
   ({ функция });
  }
  </script>

Comment: Ошибки лезут и jquery.min.js:4

Comment: n.ajaxTransport.send и n.extend.ajax

Comment: Закомментил - require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php'); и ошибка ушла. Теперь нужно заставить срабатывать - $price = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT price FROM prices where years = ".$_GET['yrs']." and pcs = ".$_GET['pcs']." and product_id = ".$_GET['pid']." limit 1 "));